# How to access cakephp model's validate from custom view template

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have created a 'form' template to bake custom theme views (Cake 2.6.0).  I am trying to access field properties from the Model's $validate array.  However, accessing $model->validate shows an empty array.  My model has several fields with rules defined in it's $validate property.

Is the $validate property not accessible while baking custom views?  If not, how do I find out whether a field is required, or if it uses 'rule =>' 'url', for example?

Comment: i don't think there is a way to access the rules from the view , i suggest to use some ajax plugin for validation where you can have the custom rules ...

Comment: It's actually not in the view.  It's in the form.ctp template the bake shell uses to create the view.  Some model attributes are available, but some, like the model's $validate array, just seem not to be set.

Comment: can you more share/describe of your code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view template(s) used by `cake bake view` are an instance of `class TemplateTask` and does not have direct access to the Model, View or Controller. What you want to do is import the controller to your custom view template:

`Console\Templates\[themename]\views\[template].ctp`

```
<?php
// The Controller's name
$controllerName = Inflector::pluralize($modelClass).'Controller';

// Import the Controller
App::import('Controller', $controllerName);

// Instantiate the Controller
$Controller = new $controllerName();

// Load the Controller's classes
$Controller->constructClasses();

//...the rest of your template
```

You now have access to your controller @ `$Controller`. To access your validate property, you would use `$Controller->{$modelClass}->validate`.